# Difference between dojo.mixin() and dojo.extend()?

Tags: dojo

I'm new to Dojo Toolkit and today I came across the topic `dojo.mixin()` and `dojo.extend()`.
I guess both are used to acquiring one object's property from another.

Can anyone explain me the difference between `dojo.mixin()` and `dojo.extend()`?

**Edit:** After reading the Dojo documentation I am clear that `dojo.extend()` is used to work on an object’s prototype.

Comment: `dojo.mixin` is deprecated, use `lang.mixin` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-mixin)

> Mixin combines two objects from right to left, overwriting the left-most object, and returning the newly mixed object for use. mixin() is very similar to extend() but only works on objects, whereas extend explicitly extends an object’s prototype.